# How to properly reference image file in java jar?

Tags: java, jpeg

Using java 1.8, I'm working with a Spring Boot jar file in which I'm including an image file into an Excel file using the xlsx4j package. I've got the code working to add the image file into the Excel file locally in my IDE, the problem is that it doesn't work after I compile the code into a jar file and deploy it to the server. I'm getting the following error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'file:/opt/app/lib/myjar.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/myimage.jpg' does not exist
```

The image file exists in the src/main/resources folder in the project, and here is the code where I get the path to this file and pass it to the code that attaches the file to the Excel file:

```
URL imageUrl = Resources.getResource("myimage.jpg");

SpreadsheetMLPackage pkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.createPackage();

WorksheetPart workSheetPart = pkg.createWorksheetPart(new PartName("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"), "Quote", 1);
Worksheet worksheet = workSheetPart.getContents();

Drawing drawingPart = new Drawing();
Relationship drawingRel = workSheetPart.addTargetPart(drawingPart);

org.xlsx4j.sml.CTDrawing drawing = org.xlsx4j.jaxb.Context.getsmlObjectFactory().createCTDrawing();
workSheetPart.getJaxbElement().setDrawing(drawing);
drawing.setId( drawingRel.getId() );

BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart
    = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(pkg, drawingPart,
            FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imageUrl.getPath()) ));      // Using path to image file here

String imageRelID = imagePart.getSourceRelationship().getId();

drawingPart.setJaxbElement(
        genericExcelUtil.buildDrawingPartContentUsingCode(imageRelID));
```

Here is the stacktrace that I'm getting on the server:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'file:/opt/app/lib/myapp.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/myimage.jpg' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1815)
    at com.myco.myapp.util.excel.FileImpl.generateExcel(FileImpl.java:113)
    at com.myco.myapp.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl.sendEmailService(EmailingServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.myco.myapp.controller.MyController.sendEmailWithDoc(MyController.java:374)
```

When doing a System.out.println of imageUrl.getPath(), this is what it looks like in my IDE:

```
/C:/Users/userid/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.3.RELEASE/myapp/target/classes/myimage.jpg
```

This is what it looks like when run on the server:

```
file:/opt/app/lib/myapp.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/myimage.jpg
```

It seems that "new File(imageUrl.getPath())" is failing because when run from the server it cannot find the file. Any ideas on how I can handle this?

Comment: `imageUrl.getPath()` *does not* return a valid filename.  Read from the URL directly, using its [openStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

you have to load it via classpath

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/in/jar")
```

https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions provided here, I was able to open an input stream to the image file, put the contents of that input stream to a ByteArrayOutputStream, convert the ByteArrayOutputStream to a byte array, and then provide the byte array to the docx4j method:

```
URL imageUrl = Resources.getResource("myimage.jpg");

InputStream imageInputStream = imageUrl.openStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((nRead = imageInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
buffer.flush();
byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart
= BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(pkg, drawingPart, byteArray);

String imageRelID = imagePart.getSourceRelationship().getId();

drawingPart.setJaxbElement(
    genericExcelUtil.buildDrawingPartContentUsingCode(imageRelID));
```

Thanks for the help!